# how to identify the connection throwing exception in establishing connection to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have connections to multiple databases in my web.config and hence many connection strings -  When I try to run the website I get the error

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible..."

How can I identify which connection among this list is causing the exception?

Comment: run in debug, see where the exception is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your code in debug when the exception is thrown then Visual Studio should break allowing you to inspect the connection element to see which one it was and what connection string you used.

Answer (score 1):

In debug mode, wait till you get exception. Get the exception at conn.Open() or in your catch, look to the connectionstring, profit.